Groups (not) quasi-retracting onto $\mathbb{Z}$
Let $X$ and $Y$ be metric spaces, with metrics $d_X$ and $d_Y$ respectively. A function $f\colon X\to Y$ is coarse Lipschitz if there exist constants $C,D>0$ such that $d_Y(f(x),f(x'))\le C d_X(x,x') +D$ for all $x,x'\in X$. A coarse Lipschitz function $f\colon X\to Y$ is a quasi-retraction if there exists a coarse Lipschitz function $g\colon Y\to X$ such that $d_Y(f(g(y)),y)\le D$ for all $y\in Y$, i.e., $f\circ g$ is uniformly close to the identity function on $Y$.
Now let $G$ be a finitely generated group, with fixed finite generating set and resulting word metric, and we can ask whether $G$ quasi-retracts onto $\mathbb{Z}$ (with the usual word metric). If $G$ is a group admitting a homomorphism onto $\mathbb{Z}$, then this homomorphism is a (quasi-)retraction, since any homomorphism onto $\mathbb{Z}$ splits. But groups with no homomorphisms onto $\mathbb{Z}$, for example perfect groups, can nonetheless quasi-retract onto $\mathbb{Z}$, e.g., it turns out Thompson's group $V$ quasi-retracts onto $\mathbb{Z}$ despite being perfect (and even simple, and even uniformly simple).
Question: What examples are there of (infinite) finitely generated groups $G$ that do not quasi-retract onto $\mathbb{Z}$?
Note that in the above, $g\colon \mathbb{Z}\to G$ is necessarily a quasi-isometric embedding. This seems potentially helpful since its image must be undistorted in some sense, but on the other hand it need not be a homomorphism, so this might not actually be so helpful. In particular, it is not even clear to me whether finitely generated torsion groups are examples.

Every infinite fg group has a QI embedding of Z (each Cayley graph has a bi-infinite geodesic). Of course this doesn't answer the question, but there is no obstruction in this direction. Also, there is a coarse retraction to $\mathbf{N}$, given by $f(x)=d(x,1)$, where $g$ is any geodesic ray.

@YCor Ah good, I sort of suspected that about bi-infinite geodesics but wasn't sure. So there's no impediment there. (And right, the monoid version is clear.) It would just seem wild to me if every f.g. group really does quasi-retract onto Z though....

Every infinite group admits a “metric retraction” to $\mathbb Z$.
Pick a bi-infinite geodesic $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb Z}$ with $x_0=1_G$ (these exist [1]) and consider the associated Busemann point
$$ f\colon\begin{pmatrix} G & \longrightarrow & \mathbb Z \\ y & \longmapsto & \lim_{n\to+\infty} d(x_n,y)-d(x_n,1_G) \end{pmatrix}$$
(This is a point in the horofunction boundary.) Then $f$ is $1$-Lipschitz, and admits a length preserving section $g(m)=x_{-m}$ (as $f(x_m)=-m$).
[1] Here is a proof of the existence of bi-infinite geodesics: consider an element of length $2l$, and $(y_m)_{0\le m\le 2l}$ a geodesic representing it. Translate it by $y_l^{-1}$ to get a long bi-geodesic. Then compactness.

Does the limit always exist? Anyway any pointwise limit will work.

Yes, the sequence is decreasing by the triangle inequality

See Lemma 3.2 in https://arxiv.org/abs/2305.02303 (or other references on horofunction boundaries and Busemann points).

Thanks for the reference. Nice argument! If I'm correct, it works on every connected graph with a bi-infinite geodesic.

Wow! From a metric geometry viewpoint, now that I see the argument it actually isn't that surprising. But from a group theory viewpoint, I still find this very surprising, that Z really is sort of a "universal target" in this coarse sense (or really the class of 2-ended groups).
